# Is the February deal Cameron made with the EU already voided?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, brexit

Is the [February deal Cameron made with the EU](https://www.theguardian.com/world/live/2016/feb/19/eu-summit-all-night-negotiations-deal-cameron-live) already voided by the EU Referendum negative Vote? And if so, how did they implement such an mechanism in the contracts?

Comment: This needs more context.  What is the February deal?

Comment: Yes. EU officials stated this themselves.

Comment: I don't see how, unless the February deal specifically states that it is null and void if a *non-binding referendum* declare's the UK populace's desire to leave the EU.

Comment: Exactly, this sounds weird. How could it be?

Comment: Also see https://www.theguardian.com/world/2016/feb/19/camerons-eu-deal-what-he-wanted-and-what-he-got

Answer (score 5):

> It is understood that, should the result of the referendum in the
>   United Kingdom be for it to leave the European Union, the set of
>   arrangements referred to in paragraph 2 above will cease to exist.

[European Council meeting (18 and 19 February 2016) – Conclusions](http://www.consilium.europa.eu/en/meetings/european-council/2016/02/EUCO-Conclusions_pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Cameron [stated so himself](https://www.gov.uk/government/speeches/pm-commons-statement-on-the-result-of-the-eu-referendum-27-june-2016) on 2016-06-27:

> The deal we negotiated at the European Council in February will now be discarded and a new negotiation to leave the EU will begin under a new Prime Minister.

AFAIK the deal was bound to a successful referendum.

Comment: Yes but I really want to know how you can possibly bind this to a referendum?

Comment: @RolandKofler: Supposedly the referendum is interpreted as rejecting the negotiated deal.